# Insert PHP code in Text

Tags: php, permalinks, code

I have this code for insert a permalink but doesn't work, return exactly code:

```
$text = '<form><td>Permalink to: <?php the_title();?></td><textarea cols="85" rows="2" readonly="readonly" onclick="select()"/><?php echo $permalink = get_permalink( $id ); ?></textarea></form>';
```

This is what currently shows up:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better, cleaner way to do this would be to use proper string return methods and concatenation.  I say this, because you're trying to put functions that echo content (i.e. `the_title()` into a variable - this won't work!!!

Instead:

```
$text = '<form><td>Permalink to: ';
$text .= get_the_title();
$text .='</td><textarea cols="85" rows="2" readonly="readonly" onclick="select()"/>';
$text .= get_permalink( $id );
$text .= '</textarea></form>';
```

Or, if you absolutely must have this in one long line:

```
$text = '<form><td>Permalink to: ' . get_the_title() . '</td><textarea cols="85" rows="2" readonly="readonly" onclick="select()"/>' . get_permalink( $id ) . '</textarea></form>';
```